# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb' in python

Tags: python, usb

To read a file from usb device used 'usb' package but im not able to import that package.

**But in my python and virtual environment there is usb module installed and it present there but still im getting this error **[image]

Im trying to read file from my usb storage using 'usb' package

## Simple i need to read the file inside my usb using python (the file located inside the usb)and i don't understand abot this error"

These are the installed packages

```
~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject$ pip freeze
asciitable==0.8.0
monitoring==0.9.12
psutil==5.9.0
pyudev==0.23.2
pyusb==1.2.1
six==1.16.0
usb==0.0.83.dev0
```

**the blow attached link that im refered now so access the usb device** https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst

**If any one know how to read a file that located  inside the USB storage using python .kindly please help**

Comment: Please correctly format your question and also use the code block to show us your code or terminal, don't use pictures.
And also please explain what you tried and what not, for instance, I don't understand why you need a module to read a file, but maybe I misunderstood your question

Comment: i need to read a file that located  inside the USB storage using python kindly please help

Comment: if you try the import from the command line does it retrieve the same error?

Comment: No, you don't want to use PyUSB to read a file on a USB mass storage device.  You should just mount the device properly so it is visible on your filesystem with `ls`, and then use Python's normal methods for opening files to open the file.

Comment: give me a refernce link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 .First make sure that you are installed this package under the right ven if not please install on that environment
2. sometimes its happens like this so just restart the pycharm and re-run the code

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to install *pyusb* (see https://pypi.org/project/pyusb/) with `pip install pyusb` and not *usb*.
Then you should be able to `import usb` and use it as expected.

Comment: This worked for me (python3.9.2 on debian 11.5)